# What makes this "declarator invalid"? C++

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have Vertex template in vertex.h. From my graph.h:

```
20 template<class edgeDecor, class vertexDecor, bool dir>
21 class Vertex;
```

which I use in my Graph template.

I've used the Vertex template successfully throughout my Graph, return pointers to Vertices, etc. Now for the first time I am trying to declare and instantiate a Vertex object, and gcc is telling me that my 'declarator' is 'invalid'. How can this be?

```
81 template<class edgeDecor, class vertexDecor, bool dir>
82 Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir> Graph<edgeDecor,vertexDecor,dir>::Dijkstra(vertex s, bool print = false) const
83 {
84    /* Construct new Graph with apropriate decorators */
85    Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir> span = new Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir>();
86    span.E.reserve(this->E.size());
87
88    typename Vertex<edgeDecor,int,dir> v = new Vertex(INT_MAX);
89    span.V = new vector<Vertex<edgeDecor,int,dir> >(this->V.size,v);
90 };
```

And gcc is saying:

```
graph.h: In member function ‘Graph<edgeDecor, int, dir> Graph<edgeDecor, vertexDecor, dir>::Dijkstra(Vertex<edgeDecor, vertexDecor, dir>, bool) const’:
graph.h:88: error: invalid declarator before ‘v’
graph.h:89: error: ‘v’ was not declared in this scope
```

I know this is probably another noob question, but I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Probably not related to this problem, but are you sure you want that "= new Vertex(INT_MAX)"?  Did you perhaps mean "vertex" uncapitalised (which I assume is a typedef)?  Also does Vertex<...> really have a ctor taking a Vertex/vertex pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igor is right. As for the following error:

```
graph.h:88: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Vertex’
```

... you probably need to say:

```
Vertex<edgeDecor,int,dir> v = new Vertex<edgeDecor,int,dir>(INT_MAX);
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably needs to be

```
Vertex<edgeDecor,int,dir> v = new Vertex(INT_MAX);
```

because you are declaring an instance of `Vertex`. `typename` keyword is only valid inside template parameter list.

Thanks **Abhay** and **outis** for pointing out valid uses of `keyword` outside the template parameter list.

After having another look at the code a number of other things come to mind:

1. As pointed out by **Mike Dinsdale** you are missing template parameters here: `new Vertex(INT_MAX);`. Try `Vertex<edgeDecor,int,dir>` instead.
2. You are assigning a pointer to a class instance. If you are creating it on the stack it should be something like this:

   Vertex v(INT_MAX);

If creating on the heap `v` must be pointer type:

```
Vertex<edgeDecor,int,dir>* v = new Vertex<edgeDecor,int,dir>(INT_MAX);
```

Comment: "typename keyword is only valid inside template parameter list", i don't think so. For template-dependent names, most compilers require you to specify *typename*.

Comment: RE dependent names: read http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html. In the OP's case, `Vertex<edgeDecor,int,dir>` isn't a dependent typename, so `typename` isn't valid.

Comment: Without the "typename" keyword gcc gives:

    graph.h:88: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Vertex’

Which makes me think "typename" is required here to indicate to the compiler that I'm referring to a type.

Comment: Does the "expected type-specifier before 'Vertex'" refer to the second Vertex, after the "new"?  It looks like you might need template arguments here...?

Comment: @mike-dinsdale: Yes, that was it, thanks.
@gman: Cool, typename is out. But Re int -> vertexDecor, I specifically want to return a Graph for which the vertex decorator should be an int. I specified it that way in my function prototype too. How should I rather do that?

Comment: @outis, `Vector<edgeDecor, int, dir>` surely is a dependent name. But it's not qualified. `typename` can only applied to *qualified* names (and those are not needed to be dependent. You might say `typename string::size_type s;` just fine).

Answer (score 0):

As said, it's a problem of misplaced `typename` first.

Some examples:

```
template <class T>
struct MyClass
{
  struct Foo { static int MBar; };
};

template <>
struct MyClass<int> { static int Foo; };
```

Using `MyClass`:

```
template <class T>
void useMyClass(T t)
{
  MyClass<T> c;
}
```

There is no need of `typename` because there is no ambiguity, the compiler knows `MyClass` got to be a type here.

```
template <class T>
void useFoo(T t)
{
  typename MyClass<T>::Foo f;
}
```

We need to disambiguate because the compiler does not know in advance if the `Foo` symbol will be a type, a method or an attribute. Indeed, if `T == int` this code is erroneous since `Foo` would represent a `static` attribute instead of being a `struct`!

```
void useFoo(int t)
{
  int f = MyClass<int>::Foo;
}

void useFoo(float t)
{
  float f = MyClass<float>::Foo::MBar;
}
```

Here `typename` is not required: since the compiler knows all the types in the template parameter list, it can instantiate the template class for `MyClass<int>` and `MyClass<float>` and as for a regular class knows the inside-out of each instantiation (and in particular what each symbol does represent).

```
template <class T>
void useBar(T t)
{
  int i = typename MyClass<T>::Foo::MBar;
}
```

Once again we need `typename` because `Foo` is a type and the compiler needs to know it.

If you don't really get it, don't worry. The `typename` and `template` keywords sometimes creep in in unusual places in generic code: just wait for the compiler error to begin with, you'll soon memorize the kind of errors and correct them in a wink.